# My code keeps printing "null" with the actual output value

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

I am trying to print numbers in the string. I created array for  storage these numbers . Here is the code :

```
String numare[] = new String[3];
String numara = "4-2-7";
int a = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numare.length; i++) {
    for (; a < numara.length(); a++) {
        if (numara.charAt(a) == '-')
            i++;
        else if (a == 0) {
            if (Character.isDigit(numara.charAt(a))) {
                numare[i]+= numara.charAt(a);
            }
        }
        else  {
            if (Character.isDigit(numara.charAt(a)))
                numare[i] += numara.charAt(a);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numare.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(numare[i]);
}
```

Here is the problem : It should print like this: 
4
2
7
But it prints : 
null4
null2
null7

I don't know where these nulls coming. Ty

Comment: Your array of String is initially filled with nulls, and then you do concatenation, adding a null value (which in String is converted to "null") to your other values. Perhaps initialize your array with empty `""` Strings first.

Comment: Thanks that is the solve for my problem ı guess but ı stuck at somewhere now. How can ı initialize all my arrays with {" " } this type.

Comment: `String numare[] = {"", "", ""};` or use `Arrays.fill(numare, "");`

Comment: I figured out ty. I created for loop to initialize each String . Ty for your help.